# Bash and sh scripts reading Here strings differently

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this line in my code:

```
    output=$(sed 's/\/$//g' <<< $output)
```

It works in `#!/bin/bash` but not in `#!/bin/sh`. In `sh` program exits with `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`, and after dissecting the error line, I've come to the conclusion that `<<<` is the problematic part. Also, in vim, vim grays out code below `<<<`, as if it is in some string.
I'm just wondering why is this happening. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes `<<<` is a zsh operator now also supported by a few other shells (including `bash`), but it still hasn't been added in the standard specification of the `sh` language and a few `sh` implementations still don't support it.

To remove a trailing `/` from the contents of a variable it's just:

```
output=${output%/}
```

If instead you wanted to remove `/` from the end of every line in `$output`¹ like that `zsh` code does, you could do:

```
output=$(printf '%s\n' "$output" | sed 's|/$||')
```

Or using the standard here-doc instead of zsh's here-string:

```
output=$(
  sed 's|/$||' << EOF
$output
EOF
)
```

Shells that support `<<<` are:

- `zsh`, since 1991
- Byron Rakitzis's clone of `rc` for Unix (though doesn't add an extra newline), since 1991 as well, and derivatives (`es`, `akanga`)
- `ksh93`, since 2002
- `bash`, since 2002
- `mksh`, since 2008
- `yash`, since 2009 (not when called as `sh`)

`sh` implementations that don't support it as of May 2020 include the Bourne shell, `ksh88`, `ash` and its derivatives (`dash`, the `sh` of busybox, FreeBSD, NetBSD), `pdksh`, `posh`, OpenBSD `sh`, `bosh`.

---

<sup>¹ And all trailing newline characters in the result, the one added by `printf` and the ones coming from `$output` if any, as a side effect of command substitution. For instance, if `$output` was `$'///\n/\n/'` (a perfectly valid file path by the way), it would become `//`.</sup>